# how to align button radio in css

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I am trying to align the button radios on my page and it seems that one of the buttons (Gender) is highly indented. The radio for the M (Gender) is at the center and the other button is at the far right. I've been changing the values in css but it doesn't align. How do I align them? Anyone help? My css is combined and I got most of help here from SO.

```css
form {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label,
input {
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  width: 30%;
}
label + input {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 10% 0 1%;
}
.label-align input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.label-align span {
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="register" class="container">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <label>*First Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Birth Date:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>M
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked>F
    <br>
    <label>*Email:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Password:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Re-enter Password:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Submit</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of this the following style.

```
label + input {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 10% 0 1%;
}
```

All inputs following a label will gain a width of 30%.
The reason only the first radio-button is affected by this is because it's the one that's adjacent to the gender label.

You could change this rule so it only affects input boxes for example.

```
label + input[type='text'] {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 10% 0 1%;
}
```

**Snippet example**

```css
form {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label,
input {
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  width: 30%;
}
label + input[type='text'] {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 10% 0 1%;
}
.label-align input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.label-align span {
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="register" class="container">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <label>*First Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Birth Date:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>M
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked>F
    <br>
    <label>*Email:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Password:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <label>*Re-enter Password:</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br>
    <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Submit</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I'm beginning to understand more of css styles. This worked to my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
label + input {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 10% 0 1%;
}
```

Remove  width :30%;

Answer (score 1):

Please add following css,

```
input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    width: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code add one class like this

```
        <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="male" checked>M
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked>F<br>
```

in your css style property add this class gender property like this.

```
 .gender{
  width: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px !important;
  }
```